# Rewrite the the wave equation using the substituion $\tau = ct$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

We have the wave equation $u_{tt} = c^2u_{xx}$ (1), and by using the substitution $\tau = ct$, we should be able to rewrite it as $u_{\tau \tau} = u_{xx}$.

I solved a similar problem with a similar substitution to rewrite the heat equation $u_{t}=ku_{xx}$ by $$\tau = kt \implies \partial u/ \partial t =\partial u/ \partial \tau \times\partial \tau/ \partial t = k\;u_{\tau} \implies u_{\tau} = u_{xx}.$$

However, I don't know what to do with (1) because of the second derivative in the LHS. I tried in a similar way but it leads to the expression $$u_{tt} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\ \partial u/\partial t = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\partial u/ \partial \tau \times\partial \tau/ \partial t) = c\;u_{t \tau}$$
from which i'm stuck. Is this the right approach, if so any hints on where I go next?

Comment: Why don't you simply repeat this for the second $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$?

Comment: I had to do some serious review of the chain rule lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\tau = ct
\\
\frac{d\tau}{d t} = c
$$
Then: chain rule
$$
\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{d v}{d\tau}\;\frac{d\tau}{dt} = c\frac{dv}{d\tau}
$$
Then: apply that twice, once with $v=du/dt$ and once with $v=u$
$$
\frac{d^2u}{dt^2} = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{du}{dt}\right)
=c\frac{d}{d\tau}\left(\frac{du}{dt}\right)
=c\frac{d}{d\tau}\left(c \frac{du}{d\tau}\right)
= c^2\frac{d^2 u}{d\tau^2}
$$